# Difference in sort order from SQL versus that of TreeList

Tags: sql, vb.net, devexpress, treelist

Within my VB.NET program I am using a Devexpress TreeList v9.2. When I run the program I fill the TreeList from a stored procedure.

When I run the SQL procedure in SQL Management Studio my data is returned the way I want it. For example

- 3
- 6
- 33
- 42
- 54
- 206
- 226
- 733
- 6633

Yet when I run the program and fill the TreeList with the same results from the Stored Procedure I get:

- 206
- 226
- 3
- 33
- 42
- 54
- 6
- 6633
- 733

Do you know what I might be doing wrong??

**EDIT:**

I do have an 'order by' in my stored procedure. That is why I am getting the right order when I run the stored procedure from within the SQL Management Studio. The order by breaks up the number as substrings (as they could also contain letters) so it appears to be sorted numerically. Somehow it looks like the TreeList is resorting it as Strings rather than keeping it with the original sort order.

**EDIT:**

I created another column containing numeric data so when I sort the table by this column ascending my data would look how I want it. But even though I sent the SortOrder in the properties it wouldn't sort even though the little triangle appeared in the header of the grid when run.

**SOLVED:**

I solved this by calling:

- tree.beginSort()
- setting the sortindex to the column I want to sort by to 0 and the others columns to -1: `tree.columns("colName").SortIndex`
- setting sortorder of my column to ascending: `tree.columns("colName").SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending`
- tree.endsort()

Comment: It looks like the TreeList it treating your numeric values as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The treeList's column is bound to a string field.  In this case, treeList thinks that this column contains string values and sorts them as strings.  To change this behavior, use the [Custom Sorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5603) approach provided by the XtraTreeList.

Comment: can's he/she just change the column datatype to int and use treeList1.Columns["someColumn"].SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;

Comment: That sounds good except my final data is "number - name" and if I do custom sorting I want "2 - ZZZZZZ" to come before "10 - AAAA". This program already has many other TreeLists with similar SQL procedures that don't undo the original sort. I compared the values associated with the TreeList and I am unsure why this one undoes the sort (or resorts) and the others don't.

Comment: add a hiden column "number" and sort by that or you can use linq to sort by that column when binding the data.

Comment: @Saif Khan I added a hidden column. How would I sort by this. I set the column sortOrder = ascending but when I run the program the triangle appears but it isn't sorted until I click on the column.

Comment: Never mind I got it by calling tree.beginSort, setting the sortindex to the column I want to sort by to 0 and the others columns to -1, setting sortorder of my column to asc and then calling tree.endsort.